# Magento 2 - getCategoryIds() returns wrong values

Tags: magento2, category, cart, quote, bug

I try to run through each item in the cart and log the category names.

But it always prints out the category names of the first item!!

The first item in my cart is in the following categories:

- Products
- insectprotection

The second item in the cart is in the following categories:

- Products
- Tools

---

Before:

```
...

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel */
    $productModel = $this->_productFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel */
    $categoryModel = $this->_categoryFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart */
    $cart = $this->_cartFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();

    $allCategories = $this->_helper->test($quote, $productModel, $categoryModel);

...
```

Helper:

```
...

public function test(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
    ,\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
    ,\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel
) {
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/shipping.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $data = [];

    foreach($quote->getItems() AS $item) {

        $product = $productModel->load($item->getProductId());
        $logger->info(PHP_EOL . "Product name: ". $product->getName());

        foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId){
            $category = $categoryModel->load($categoryId);
            $logger->info("Category name: " . $category->getName());
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

This is getting logged:

> ```
> Product name: VKB1 Test (Rollo Plisse 2)
> 2020-09-09T12:47:28+00:00 INFO (6): Category name: Products
> 2020-09-09T12:47:28+00:00 INFO (6): Category name: Insectprotection
>
> Product name: VKB1 Test (Drehrahmen)
> 2020-09-09T12:47:28+00:00 INFO (6): Category name: Products
> 2020-09-09T12:47:28+00:00 INFO (6): Category name: Insectprotection
> ```

As you can see, it logs the same categories as for the first item.

I already tried `php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento c:f`

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

---

### Attempt #2 (failed):

```
...

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collectionModel */
    $collectionModel = $this->_collectionFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel */
    $categoryModel = $this->_categoryFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart */
    $cart = $this->_cartFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();

    $allCategories = $this->_helper->test($quote, $categoryModel, $collectionModel);

...
```

Helper:

```
public function test(
    $quote
    ,$categoryModel
    ,$collectionModel
) {
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/shipping.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $data = [];

    foreach($quote->getItems() AS $item) {

        $product = $collectionModel->addFieldToSelect("*")
                                   ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", ['eq' => $item->getProductId()]);

        $logger->info(PHP_EOL . "-------------------------------------");
        $logger->info("itemId: ". $item->getProductId());
        $logger->info($product->getData());
        $logger->info("-------------------------------------" . PHP_EOL);

        foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId){
            $category = $categoryModel->load($categoryId);
            $logger->info("Category name: " . $category->getName());
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Output (does not contain category information, so it fails):

```
2020-09-09T14:20:04+00:00 INFO (6): itemId: 7045
2020-09-09T14:20:04+00:00 INFO (6): array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'entity_id' => '7045',
    'attribute_set_id' => '40',
    'type_id' => 'virtual',
    'sku' => 'VKB1 Test (Rollo Plisse 2)',
    'has_options' => '1',
    'required_options' => '1',
    'created_at' => '2020-09-09 10:45:25',
    'updated_at' => '2020-09-09 10:47:39',
    'row_id' => '7045',
    'created_in' => '1',
    'updated_in' => '2147483647',
  ),
)
2020-09-09T14:20:04+00:00 INFO (6): -------------------------------------
```

Comment: you should recreate the models via factory before loading them

Comment: I already create the models with factories and pass them to my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get your products with repositories, or at least create the model with factories. I've already noticed that not using the good practice can create this kind of issue because under the hood it's not exactly the same methods called.

Try to update and use `ProductRepository`.

You can also have a look into your database directly to check if your datas are what you are expecting in there.

EDIT : Sorry I've been a little too fast, what you need is not the product repository but the product collection factory

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory

 /**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $productCollection;

    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $productCollection){
       $this->productCollection = $productCollection
}
```

EDIT 2 : This might work too

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

 /**
 * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository; 

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

    $sku = 'the sku you are looking';
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
```

With that you should have the product with the good method. If the $product->getCategory() isn't good at this point the issue is in your data.

Comment: I updated my question to show more code. Where shoud I use `ProductRepository` in my code? Do you mean instead of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` I should use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepositoryFactory` ?

Comment: Thank you for your edit, I will try it out and report back.

Comment: I've been a little too fast in my answer I updated. I don't think the repository has access to the get method we need, you can go with the collection factory then use ->create()->addFieldToSelect('....');

Comment: Thank you sir. I have to lookup how addFieldToSelect works.

Comment: It takes as an argument the field name in database that you are looking for (I think * should work too if you want to get everything). There also might be a method addFieldToFilter to select for exemple on the specific entity_id you are looking for.

Comment: I've been adding the repository method

Comment: I tried the approach with productCollection, but it does not contain the category ids.
`$product = $collectionModel->addFieldToSelect("*")->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", ['eq' => $item->getProductId()]);` -> `$logger->info($product->getData());` <-- Does not contain category_ids

Comment: Your second approach with `ProductRepositoryInterface` works!

Comment: Sorry it was my first idea repository but I didn't found the class and in fact she was hidden in an API folder. I'm glad it worked for you. Remember to use Factory and Repository each time you can to avoid this kind of issue.