# Magento 2 - Get Category show the same value

Tags: magento2, category

I am trying to get the category name of a series of products. When I show the products individually the category is correct and changes but when I show more than one product it always shows me the category of the first in all the other products.

My test code is:

```
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2510);

        $CodigoArticulo = $product->getSku();
        $articulo = $product->getName();
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
                


        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<p class='text-bold'>Código artículo: ".$CodigoArticulo."</p>";
        echo "<p class='text-bold'>Artículo: ".$articulo."</p>";
        echo "<p>Categoria Ids:</p>";
        echo "<p>".var_dump($cats)."</p>";
        foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
            $_cat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id) ;
            echo "<p>Categoria Name: ".$_cat->getName()."</p>";
        } 
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr>";


        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(3167);

        $CodigoArticulo = $product->getSku();
        $articulo = $product->getName();
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
                


        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<p class='text-bold'>Código artículo: ".$CodigoArticulo."</p>";
        echo "<p class='text-bold'>Artículo: ".$articulo."</p>";
        echo "<p>Categoria Ids:</p>";
        echo "<p>".var_dump($cats)."</p>";
        foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
            $_cat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id) ;
            echo "<p>Categoria Name: ".$_cat->getName()."</p>";
        } 
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr>";
```

*I know that it is not a code optimized in real environment, I use a for each, it is only for testing.*

The result is the same ('Categoria name'):

[image]

But I run only a product show the correct category:

```
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(3167);

        $CodigoArticulo = $product->getSku();
        $articulo = $product->getName();
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
                


        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<p class='text-bold'>Código artículo: ".$CodigoArticulo."</p>";
        echo "<p class='text-bold'>Artículo: ".$articulo."</p>";
        echo "<p>Categoria Ids:</p>";
        echo "<p>".var_dump($cats)."</p>";
        foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
            $_cat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id) ;
            echo "<p>Categoria Name: ".$_cat->getName()."</p>";
        } 
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr>";
```

The result:

[image]

At this point I am confused because I do not understand why if I show the products individually, it correctly shows me the name of the category, instead when I show more than one it shows me the category of the first one in all the products.

Maybe someone can me help.

Comment: Did you try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321947/magento-2-getcategoryids-returns-wrong-values ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the post but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectManager::get` returns a singleton instance of the class, you are calling `getCategoryIds` from the same object even you load with a different ID, that is why it returned the same value.

`ObjectManager::create` would return a new instance and will solve your issue.

However, `ObjectManager` should never be called explicitly, you should inject the product repository instead.

Comment: Ok I understand is the same object but I'm not an expert of Magento and I don't know how to use the product repository class.